# Generating random paths for finding hidden objects in a game world

Tags: algorithm, artificial-intelligence, graph-algorithm, path-finding

Let's assume we have a 3D game world. The game world is divided in sections of 1x1x1 cubes (nodes in a graph), each uniquely defined by it's position. Let's further suppose the world has solid obstacles like walls and boxes that you can't move through, as well as certain objects of interest, that can be hidden behind a wall etc, that you have to find by moving around in the world. You can move in all 3 directions and all objects can float, also you have a limited field of view.

Target: find all objects of interest in an automated way.

My question: How would you go about it? 
I'm mostly looking for ideas and concepts but detailed explanations are welcome as well.

For now I'm thinking about keeping track of everything that has already been seen and move around to places not yet seen. But I feel like this is going to be highly inefficient.

Thanks

Comment: Do you tried some path finding algorithm like Breadth first search, A*?

Comment: I'm using theta* (A* with a little extra step) for pathfinding, but these algorithms need a point A and B to calculate a path. I don't know where to put point B as I don't know where the target is. I have to move around the world and look around, when I see a target, then I have a point B and I can use a pathfinding algorithm to go there.

Comment: seems more like traversing the entire graph. A DFS might be more helpful, I guess. Analogy may be every 3D cell as node and edges are passage from 1 node to another. May be some nodes have special attributes u may want to collect. Limited field of view can be related to only connected nodes from current node(or cell).